# Join tables and return row with latest timestamp

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

### table 1: product

```
id
product_title
```

### table 2: product_stats

```
id
product_id
stock
timestamp
```

I want to join the `product_stats` table and display the stock for the latest timestamp.

This is what I've got so far..

```
SELECT `p`.*, `s`.*
FROM `product` `p`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `stock`, `product_id`, `timestamp`
FROM `product_stats`
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
 LIMIT 1) s ON `s`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
```

Been struggling with this for the last couple days, so a solution would be very appreciated!

**UPDATE/FIXED**

And ofcourse, for some reason when I finally post the question I finally got a solution. check it here:

```
SELECT    p.product_title, st.timestamp, st.stock
FROM      product p
JOIN      (
              SELECT    MAX(id) max_id, product_id 
              FROM      product_stats
              GROUP BY  product_id
          ) c_max ON (c_max.product_id = p.id)
JOIN      product_stats st ON (st.id = c_max.max_id)
```

Comment: Your query is right I think.

Comment: It looks good to me, too. What problem are you having? If it's not returning the expected results, show some sample data and the expected result.